# How to execute this query: SELECT table_row FROM table AS concat(sth, sth)? Returning error at the concat, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Employee_Dilligence(IN No_Hours INT)
BEGIN 
SELECT EmpName,employees.EmpID, Hours_Worked, 
        Dilligence(Hours_Worked/(TIMESTAMPDIFF(Day, StartDate, CURDATE())*No_Hours)) 
        AS concat('Worked more than', No_Hours, 'Hours')
    
FROM company.employees INNER JOIN company.employee_project INNER JOIN company.projects
ON employees.EmpID = employee_project.EmpID AND employee_project.ProjID = projects.ProjID
WHERE projects.ProjID = ProjectID;
```

And it works correctly, except for one thing: the `concat` here:

```
AS concat('Worked more than', No_Hours, 'Hours')
```

I do not understand why, though. The error message I'm getting is:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
 MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('Worked more than', No_Hours, 'hours per day')      
FROM company.employees INNER JOIN c' at line 5
```

Yet it looks like I am using concat correctly, so how can I fix this problem? If I replace the problematic line with just:

```
AS N_Hours_Worked_Per_Day
```

then it works fine, but isn't as nice.

The expected output I want would look something like this:

```
Employee_Dilligence(2)

#COLUMN NAMES OF OUTPUT:

EmpName | EmpID | Hours_Worked | Worked more than 2 hours per day

Employee_Dilligence(3)

#COLUMN NAMES OF OUTPUT:

EmpName | EmpID | Hours_Worked | Worked more than 3 hours per day
```

Comment: `AS` wants an alias, a name used to represent the data you're aliasing, so it can't accept a function (at least, for what I know)

Comment: If so, could you suggest a way to get the output I want? Like would I need to define a function or something? @Marco

Comment: @Fenistil has already given an answer about this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `CONCAT` as an alias for a field in MySQL. The alias must be a string, this will be the field's name in your result.

To build an SQL that include a variable as a fieldname, you can use a `prepared statement` with the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE Employee_Dilligence(IN No_Hours INT)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT EmpName,employees.EmpID, Hours_Worked, Dilligence(Hours_Worked/(TIMESTAMPDIFF(Day, StartDate, CURDATE())*',No_Hours,')) AS "Worked more than', No_Hours, 'Hours" FROM company.employees INNER JOIN company.employee_project INNER JOIN company.projects ON employees.EmpID = employee_project.EmpID AND employee_project.ProjID = projects.ProjID WHERE projects.ProjID = ProjectID;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

With this you first make your query as a string, then make a prepared statement from it, which can be executed by the server.

Comment: Hi thanks for the explanation, but what I want is an output like the expected output I posted in the question, where the field name, not the field, has the equivalent of a concat effect. Is that possible?

Comment: @PythonHacks999 I see now, sorry, I've misunderstand your question. I've modified my answer to satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing a syntax error. please see blow how to use concate in query.

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS 'Name', dept FROM users;
```

Comment: That is not what I want, I want the column name to be somewhat dynamic, and the way I've tried to achieve that is through concat